cant seem enable wifi adapter (ideapad slim 5 16irl -type 82xf / lenovo)
i installed ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver but can't seem to make the wifi adapter work
here are some outputs for some codes i researched hope it can give more info
asol@asol-IdeaPad-Slim-5-16IRL8:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)


asol@asol-IdeaPad-Slim-5-16IRL8:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -43


Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51ef] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:383c]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:382f]


Ubuntu 18.04 is a six year old version and reached end of support last year. Newer versions of Ubuntu generally have better support for newer hardware. Please install ubuntu 24.04, and ask a new question if it does not work

This question will be closed as 18.04 is unsupported

ill give it a try thank you for the advice

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.
